# Repeating the noun when we referring to it multiple times using different adjectives

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

Is it necessary to repeat the noun when we referring to it multiple times using different adjectives?

Here are 3 variations to compare.

- The first one looks correct from grammatical point of view, but very cumbersome and ugly.
- The third one is short and nice, but I'm not sure such phrasing is correct.
- The second one is somewhat between.

Variation 1:

> There are two types of hypervisors:
>
> - **type-1 hypervisors** (also known as **native** or **bare-metal** hypervisors), which have better performance, and
> - **type-2 hypervisors** (also known as **hosted** hypervisors), which are easier to use.

Variation 2:

> There are two types of hypervisors:
>
> - **type-1 hypervisors** (also known as **native** or **bare-metal** ones), which have better performance, and
> - **type-2 hypervisors** (also known as **hosted** ones), which are easier to use.

Variation 3:

> There are two types of hypervisors:
>
> - **type-1 hypervisors** (also known as **native** or **bare-metal**), which have better performance, and
> - **type-2 hypervisors** (also known as **hosted**), which are easier to use.

Comment: I think this may be be  case of 'straining at a gnat'.  The avoidance of repetition is not an end in itself.  When we are talking about technical explanation, repetition is, if anything, good, because it helps the reader to memorise the key concepts, as in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical prose has a very different aim to literary prose: technical prose should be as unambiguous as possible. With this in mind, Variation 1 is in my view by far the best. The problem with Variation 3 is that the uninformed reader is left with two alternatives: is a certain kind of type-1 hypervisor known as a **native**, or as a **native hypervisor**? I realise that the reader will probably be able to work this out for themselves, but why give them the choice?

And your Variation 2 is just the worst of both worlds.

Comment: I'd also go with (1), but 'hypervisors' should be bolded every time for symmetry of structure. Perhaps even  <<  **type-1 hypervisors** (also known as **native hypervisors** or **bare-metal hypervisors**), which have better performance >>.

Comment: I upvoted and agree with your reasoning. But lets assume this example was taken from not-so-technical-paper. Is variation OK in that case?

Comment: It certainly looks like a technical paper to me! You don't see bullet points in Tolstoy or Jane Austen. And in fact those bullet points play the same role as the repetition of the noun: they make it easier to convey information unambiguously.

Comment: Well, yeah, I agree. But it's quite easy to imagine another example without bullets, but with the same issue of repetitive nouns.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree, thanks a lot.

Comment: @johnc.j.: I can't imagine another example that talks about type-1 hypervisors but isn't technical prose. Unless it's by Thomas Pynchon, of course.

Comment: Of course, we aren't limited to hypervisors. It could be something like "There are two types of writers:..." Well, I can't came up with a complete example right now, but I believe the idea is very simple.

Comment: @johnc.j.: you just don't give up, do you? Hypervisors are not the same as writers. Obviously. For one thing, there are _exactly_ two types of hypervisor.